# Does internalization loses informations everywhere?

Tags: logic, category-theory, foundations, topos-theory

It is well known that a group object in Grp is necessarily abelian. This can be understood as "internalization loses information". Indeed, if one was to study group theory by looking at group objects in Grp, one would conclude that all groups are abelians.

It is also well known that mathematical logic is usually done in the sense of "let's internalize our theory inside itself and study it from there". Yet, it is highly possible than such internalized theory is much weaker than the original one we started with. That is, by looking at it, one would make wrong conclusions about the original theory.

So, my question is simple: is it known, in some specific sense, that internalization of set theory is different than the one we started from?
This question could also be formulated as "Does a topos object in a Topos "loses" information ?".

Thanks.

Comment: What is Grp in the first place?

Comment: the category of groups

Comment: Then how is an object in Grp necessarily abelaian?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object

Comment: Ah, I left out one word in reading ...

Answer (score 6):

You say that internalization in $\mathsf{Grp}$ "loses information". This presupposes that there is some natural way to compare group objects in $\mathsf{Grp}$ to group objects in $\mathsf{Set}$. Although there is a natural comparison in this case (induced by the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Set}$), there won't be such a natural comparison between groups internal to $\mathcal{C}$ and groups internal to $\mathcal{D}$ in general. So I would prefer to simply say that groups internal to $\mathsf{Grp}$ are "less rich" than groups internal to $\mathsf{Set}$.

That being said, I would say that it is definitely *not* generally true that group objects in $\mathcal{C}$ are less rich than group objects in $\mathsf{Set}$. For example, group objects in the category $\mathsf{Top}$ of topological spaces are topological groups, which are *richer* than group objects in $\mathsf{Set}$ (In fact, it contains the category of groups in $\mathsf{Set}$ as the subcategory of discrete groups). Group objects internal to the category $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ of sheaves on a space $X$ are sheaves of groups, which are also richer than group objects in $\mathsf{Set}$ (and they contain the category of group objects in $\mathsf{Set}$ as the subcategory of constant sheaves).

Similar remarks apply to set theory. For example, the topos $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ of sheaves on a space $X$ (a topos object in $\mathsf{Set}$) is a *richer* category than $\mathsf{Set}$ (and it contains $\mathsf{Set}$ as the subcategory of constant sheaves).

Sometimes things come out somewhere in the middle. For example, <strike>group</strike> monoid objects in the category $\mathsf{Ord}$ of ordered sets are ordered <strike>groups</strike> monoids; not every <strike>group</strike> monoid admits an order, so in that sense ordered <strike>groups</strike> monoids are less rich than <strike>groups</strike> monoids, but the order is an additional structure and the same <strike>group</strike> monoid can admit many different orders, so in that sense ordered <strike>groups</strike> monoids are more rich than <strike>groups</strike> monoids.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand in what sense the group objects in, say, Top, are richers than the category of Grp itself as a whole (seen as the full subcategory of group object in Sets).
For a "structure" (object) constructed with set theory to be a group in some sense, it clearly has to be a representation of an usual group. Moreover, it is clear that an arrow in Top is also an arrow in Set but the contrary is not true.

Thus, there must exists some kind of forgetful functor from the category of group object in Top to the category of group object in Sets, that would be **at best** an equivalence

Comment: @tcamps Aren't ordered groups usually defined to have an order-reversing inverse operation?

Comment: Some little though: if a category in the usual sense is a "1-dimensional object", can we understand a group object in Grp as a 1-dimensional "categorical" representation of a group? Thus, the abelian nature of all group objects in Grp would be understood as some categorical Schur's lemma ?

Comment: This would be compatible with the fact that a group object in Top is a **representation** of some group in terms of topological spaces. Hence, it is not surprising that you find a richer representation theory in Top that in Grp, but this does not mean at all that all groups are representable in Top (it is the case yet, as you said, as discrete groups).

Comment: @ZhenLin Of course you are totally right. I've switched my example to ordered monoids.

Comment: @sure My intuition is that $\mathsf{Set}$ is in some sense one of the "simplest" categories of "set-like" objects. So if you have a concept that is interesting in $\mathsf{Set}$ and internalize it to a category of set-like or space-like objects, you are likely to obtain a notion which is at least as rich and likely richer. On the other hand, if you internalize an "algebraic" concept like groups into another "algebraic" category, the operations of the two are more likely to interact and produce new restrictions on the structure of the objects involved. Not sure about your Schur analogy :).

Comment: I would rather see a group object in some (non necessarily) abstract category $C$ as a functor $Th(Grp) \rightarrow C$. $Th(Grp)$ being a category that has $1$, $G$, $G\times G$, $(G \times G) \times G$ and $G \times (G \times G)$ as objects, all the projections, universal arrows and the product map $m$, inverse map $i$, and unit map $u$ which respect the obvious axioms.
Now, given a (non necessarily) abstract category $C$, one is always free to consider the category $GrpObj(\mathcal{C})$ whose objects are all the representations of $Th(Grp)$ and arrows the natural transformations.

Comment: So a group object in $\mathcal{C}$ is a representation of $Th(Grp)$, that is, a product/limit preserving functor. What you do when you say that some group objects are richer than others, is comparing the theory of representations of $Th(Grp)$, nothing else. What is a representation? It's nothing else than a model of some theory in another theory. In this respect, (representation of) group theory is "as complete" in $Sets$ as it is in $Top$, but it is really bad in Grp. Now, there clearly must exists some kind of concept to tell you that it is the case. I'll try to think about it.